# mysql 5.7 to 5.8 upgrade bump into upgrade error "Unknown storage engine 'partition'"

Tags: mysql

I recently try to upgrade my MySQL server from 5.6 to 8.0. Since we cannot skip major version, I first upgraded 5.6 to 5.7. The upgrade process took a while but it was a success (windows server OS, using zip archive replacement).

However after I replaced 5.7 with 8.0 binaries and start the mysql service, it ran into error that I could not figure out what is wrong:

```
[System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
[ERROR] [MY-013140] [Server] Unknown storage engine 'partition'
[ERROR] [MY-013140] [Server] Can't find file: '.\some_db\some_table.frm' (errno: 0 - No error)
[ERROR] [MY-013137] [Server] Can't find file: '.\some_db\some_table.frm' (OS errno: 0 - No error)
[ERROR] [MY-010348] [Server] Error in reading file .\some_db\some_table.frm
[ERROR] [MY-010758] [Server] Error in creating TABLE_SHARE from some_table.frm file.
```

I understand server partitions no longer supported in mysql 8, however "some_table" is a table with innodb partitioning. It is using Innodb storage engine. I do not understand why the error says 'partition' storage engine, as well as unable to find the .frm file. anyone encounter similar issue before?

Comment: When performing an upgrade, tables which are partitioned by KEY must be dumped and reloaded. Partitioned tables using storage engines other than InnoDB cannot be upgraded from MySQL 5.7 or earlier to MySQL 8.0 or later; you must either drop the partitioning from such tables with ALTER TABLE ... REMOVE PARTITIONING or convert them to InnoDB using ALTER TABLE ... ENGINE=INNODB prior to the upgrade.

Comment: yes I read this clause, however the mysql_upgrade process was incomplete. See my answer below, additional upgrade partitioning command has to be issued to each partitioned table (InnoDB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For record, I found the rootcause after going thru mysql documentation again. Looks like the latest mysql 5.7 (5.7.21) does not perform partition upgrade or partition check. I have to perform below command on all affected tables prior to upgrading the server to 8.0.

```
ALTER TABLE some_db.some_table UPGRADE PARTITIONING;
```

Once this is done in all tables (very quick process, just metadata changes), the upgrade to 8.0 has no issue whatsoever. The thing that I do not understand is why later version of 5.7.x does not complete this step in mysql_upgrade, and I am not sure what was done in those partitioned tables during mysql_upgrade that took almost 2 days to complete. Maybe MySQL dev team has a reason for it, but to me this just make no sense.